# .Net web services on linux

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, monodevelop

I have implemented some web services in .net and hosted it on windows server, how I can port it to linux ? To have the same web services on linux machine, do  I have to rewrite it in Java ? Any Ideas.

Comment: The question is really to vague to answer intelligently.  Q: Can you do web services in .Net?  A: Yes, there are many, many ways.  For starters, look at Mono: http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Linux  Q: Can I implement the *same* web service in a *different* language from C# and/or a *different* environment from Mono/.Net?  A: Sure.  Look at JWS: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137004.html.

Comment: Thanks Paulsm,I have tried to rephrase it.

Comment: Thanx: the rephrasing helped.  Q: I wrote C# .net services in Windows.  Can I port it directly to Linux?  A: Yes: you should be able to recompile and run your .Net web app in Mono.  The only "gotcha" might be Interop code.

Answer (score 3):

A very wide scope of question , so here is a general answer

If you have implemented the service in WCF then mono ( .net on Linux ) ha limited support for it. For all the known issues look at

http://www.mono-project.com/WCF_Development

I have done this before for simple services without much problem.

If you need to support web services on both windows and Linux ,then I can recomend an alternative to WCF

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack

Use this to avoid porting effort. This way you won't have to rewrite in java and reuse some of you .net code.

Comment: So what's the alternative?