# What cross-platform coding language should I use?

Tags: cross-platform, programming-languages, portability

by cross-platform I mainly intend Windows and Debian, I do not need a GUI. I need to elaborate text, write/edit files. Programs may need to accept command-line arguments and in some cases prompt for user interaction (input) some programs may need to access an internet connection and send/receive data.

It would be a plus if I could make it use web services written in .net Im not worried about the learning curve however the more simple the better.

Another plus would be the ability to create/interact with databases, possibly using common SQL strings, but I'm open minded.

Comment: Check out Xojo. It makes native apps for Windows, Linux (and macOS) -- both desktop and console. Plus it can also make web apps, services and iOS apps. http://www.xojo.com

Answer (score 1):

Python/Java/C# Good option for the requirement.
For java
U can use jdbc in ecillipse/netbean for connecting sql and for web base applications
Python is an interpreted high-level programming language for general-purpose programming.Python is simple to learn and understand

For .net in debian u can follow:

http://www.mono-project.com/WCF_Development 
If you need to support web services on both windows and Linux ,then I can recomend an alternative to WCF

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack

Use this to avoid porting effort. 
refer this 
[.Net web services on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591852/net-web-services-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

You are just looking for a portable language that is easy to use for both Windows and Debian both Java and Python are good choices. Python is especially simple and easy to pick up when it comes to scripts about file manipulations and file management. Also there are python libraries that can connect to an SQL database and send queries ([How do I connect to a SQL server database with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149243/how-do-i-connect-to-a-sql-server-database-with-python))

The portability is really simple as well in python. Most Debian installs have python pre-installed and for windows you just need to install the correct version of python from their website(https://www.python.org/downloads/)